# Change Input value

Tags: html, css

I have this simple input

```
<input name="params" id="param-USERNAME" class="form-control" placeholder="The input is passed from OUTPUT" value="I dont want to show this" readonly="">
```

**I need to have a value** but I don't actually want to display it but **I want to see the placeholder**, so `color: transparent` doesn't cut it.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try using data-value attribute in your html instead of value.

```html
<input name="params" id="param" class="form-control" placeholder="The input is passed from OUTPUT" data-value="I dont want to show this" readonly>
```

And if you need to access the data in your javascript you could try the following.

```js
x = document.getElementById("param").getAttribute("data-value");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have a white background you could try to make the font color of the input white

Comment: You are just changing the color of the value but the value is still gong to be there

Comment: yeah I dont want that. I still want to show the placeholder

Comment: Please check [how to answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering) Adding more details with illustration helps